# How to read image in cuda program?

Tags: opencv, cuda

Cant find opencv lib when run a cuda program.

I did some processing for my images by c++, and it works. But it is too slow for real-time system. Then I try to do it by cuda.
When I run my .cu file by "nvcc test.cu", it has an error that "identifier "Mat" is undefined" which means cuda cant find opencv lib. any idea to fix it?

Comment: That sounds like a compilation error, not a runtime error, in which case your diagnosis is completely wrong

Comment: Please provide more details such as operating system, IDE and the complete compilation commands you are using to compile the code.

Comment: I fix it by using cmake rather than nvcc, then I can find opencv in CMakeLists.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed by using cmake rather than nvcc. OpenCV can be found by CmakeLists.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules) modules with CUDA.

1. Make OpenCV with [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib), check -DWITH_CUDA=ON. And check -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON
2. Use cv::cuda::GpuMat instead cv::Mat
3. Learn about [default CUDA examples](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/gpu).

Comment: That is not correct. There is no need of `opencv_contrib` module for using `cv::cuda::GpuMat` class. Also, the question is about undefined `Mat` identifier which does not have any direct link with GPU functionality.

Comment: Yes, but it contains a lot of cuda modules. See you my links

Comment: And with cudacodec you can decode video direct to the gpuMat without double copy frame to host memory and back to the video memory.